# Ignoring files/paths with RegEx in VisualHG

Tags: mercurial, visualhg

I am using VisualHG 1.0.7 and cannot seem to ignore the files that I want.

The behavior I am experiencing is the RegEx values I enter for ignoring files appears to only be applied to items marked as ?: unknown.

What I am looking for is a way to add RegEx values to ignore the following:

- files in any bin directory
- files in any obj directory
- files with the cache extension
- files with the suo extension

I can write the correct RegEx but they aren't being applied to all of the files in the commit view.

Should I just 'forget' these files, or is there another way I should be accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design: hgignore rules are for untracked files only - so you must exclude the files from the repository.

Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101167/what-is-the-difference-between-hg-forget-and-hg-remove/1101902#1101902) answer for details about '`hg forget`'