# How to hg forget what .hgignore lists?

Tags: unix, version-control, mercurial, hgignore

I've tracked files I no longer want to track. So I've updated `.hgignore` but that doesn't result in them being forgotten. Other than manually `hg forget` each do I have other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is another option.

You have already checked these files into
Mercurial.After `hg forget` the .hgignore file will take effect
and prevent them from being added again. More precisely, the `.hgignore`
file will make `hg status` stop showing the files as untracked

Tracked files are never affected by the `.hgignore` file. Well `hg addremove` could help you. Take a look [here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html).

Answer (score 7):

With Mercurial 2.0, you can specify a [fileset](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#filesets) for this! To forget the ignored files, use:

```
$ hg forget "set:hgignore() and not ignored()"
```

Comment: Won't pushes and pulls from this repo to another schedule those files for deletion? Or will the ignore file kick in and keep this from happening?

Comment: @ErikReppen: A forgotten file is like a removed file, except that it is left behind in *your* working copy. So you're correct that `hg update` in another repository will remove these ignored files from the working copy. The ignore file only serves to cleanup the output from `hg status`, it doens't affect `hg update`.

Comment: Experimented last night and it doesn't appear to remove on a pull if it's in an ignore file. I think the idea is that the remove also removes it from tracking which allows the ignore file to do its thing. I don't get it. This effectively "untracks" for purposes of interaction with other repos. Why allow tracking status to overrule explicitly listed ignore file status? Having to add to an ignore file and then forget actually being a delete operation where the changesets are concerned has lead to more confusion on our team than it saved. I'll go bug them on... whatever hub they're on.

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9930217/110204) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12050113/110204). They should clear it up!