# How to prevent ignored files from being removed?

Tags: mercurial

I version controlled a project settings folder a couple months back on my default branch, and then over time created many branches off default. Now I've decided that I'd rather not have the project settings folder version controlled as it creates a lot of problems when switching between branches.

So I've `hg forget`'d this project settings folder which lets me keep the files on my local machine but removes them mercurial. However, when switching from one of the old branches which still have this folder versioned back to the default branch it actually removes the files from the local machine, which is bad.

How do I prevent that?

The folder is also in `.hgignore` on default now.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to do.

But the common practice is to keep `config.ini.dist` in your repository and build environment-specific config by some build-system right after you check source code out.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to deal with this is to version control a **template config file** and ignore the real config file. The real config file can then include the template file, or maybe the template file is copied over once in a while.

The underlying reason for your problems is that running:

```
$ hg forget config.ini
```

is **exactly the same** as running:

```
$ hg remove config.ini
$ hg cat config.ini > config.ini
```

The forget command leaves the file behind in your working directory, but what you commit is still a file removal. This means that afterwards, Mercurial cannot distinguish between "file was forgotten" and "file was removed" — only the removal is committed, so the two commands look exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry when I said "project settings" I meant the ones my IDE creates, nothing to do with my framework. I understand why it's happening, but I was hoping there was some clever way of getting around that... perhaps some script that would go into each branch and then ignore the files so that when I switch branches it simply does nothing with those files.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to remove the files and update the ignore file yourself on each branch.