# Mercurial Stop Tracking and Ignore

Tags: version-control, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

When it comes to Mercurial;

What exactly is the difference between the following:

- Stop Tracking
- Ignore

Google Search, SE search brings no clear examples / results on the matter.

Comment: If this is about TortoiseHG or another GUI for Mercurial, please tag it as such. Otherwise, it isn't clear which commands you are referring to...

Comment: @codesparkle, it's already been tagged though. The GUI in question is: source tree (Atlassian)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realized that was the name of the product. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @codesparkle, not at all. I should be the one thanking for your simple, clear answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally speaking, as it isn't clear in what context you came across those terms:

- [**Ignore**](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html#id382104) adds a file name pattern to the `.hgignore` file. It means any files matching the pattern will not be version controlled ***unless** they have already been added* (by `hg add` or `hg addrem`). So any files that are already part of the repository will not be affected by `.hgignore`.
- [**Stop Tracking**](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html#id361518) ([`hg remove` or `hg forget`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101902/1106367)) means that Mercurial will not record any changes made to the file and the file will no longer be part of the repository. If the file is still present in the file system, it will show up as `?` (not tracked). This action takes effect with the next commit, *not immediately*.

Comment: So is it possible to ignore after stop-tracking a file currently part of the repository? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. You can either add the file name to `.hgignore` manually or (probably) through Atlassian source tree.