# TortoiseHG forget files in all sub folders of specific name

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a pretty large folder (with many sub folders) on a mercurial repository. I was a bit too fast with my first commit so I added a lot of files that i now realize shouldn't be on version control. I've updated my .hgignore file accordingly but all the old files are still version controlled. Is there a command that I can write in the root directory that forgets all files that are in a folder of a specific name. These folder names exist in a lot of places and i want them all forgotten with one command since it would take a long time to go through them all manually and forget the folders/files

I guess it would maybe look something like this:

> hg ignore ../folderName/

Comment: Please note that if you have shared this repo with others, when they `hg update` to the chageset where you `hg forgot` those files, those files will be **deleted** on their machine! (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9930217) for how `forget` relates to `remove`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes... use a pattern to match them like

```
hg forget FOLDERNAME**
hg commit -m "Forget FOLDERNAME"

hg help forget
hg forget [OPTION]... FILE...
(...)
options ([+] can be repeated):
 -I --include PATTERN [+] include names matching the given patterns
```

or use a one-line script:

```
for i in $(hg ma | grep FOLDERNAME); do hg forget $i; done
```

Comment: Sure, why not :) I just didn't think of them

Answer (score 1):

You can read `hg help filesets` and use one of it's samples

> - Forget files that are in .hgignore but are already tracked:
>
>   `hg forget "set:hgignore() and not ignored()"`